# How to create JSON with PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have one small problem and can't move on.

I wrote this PHP code:

```
 $d=array();
 foreach(range(0, 3) as $rs) {
    foreach(range(0, 5) as $c){

       //here is working php code to generate '$randomRs' by '$rs' and '$c' vars..

       $d[] = array('rs'.$rs => array('c'.$c => $randomRs));

    }
}
echo json_encode($d);
```

Now JSON output is:

```
[{"rs0":{"c0":"bl"}},{"rs0":{"c1":"pl"}},{"rs0":{"c2":"bl"}},{"rs0":{"c3":"pl"}},{"rs0":{"c4":"pl"}},{"rs0":{"c5":"wd1"}},{"rs1":{"c0":"lk"}},{"rs1":{"c1":"gr"}},{"rs1":{"c2":"lk"}},{"rs1":{"c3":"gr"}},{"rs1":{"c4":"lk"}},{"rs1":{"c5":"gr"}},{"rs2":{"c0":"u1"}},{"rs2":{"c1":"u1"}},{"rs2":{"c2":"u1"}},{"rs2":{"c3":"wt"}},{"rs2":{"c4":"u1"}},{"rs2":{"c5":"u1"}},{"rs3":{"c0":"u1"}},{"rs3":{"c1":"u1"}},{"rs3":{"c2":"u1"}},{"rs3":{"c3":"u1"}},{"rs3":{"c4":"cl"}},{"rs3":{"c5":"ir"}}]
```

Which is wrong. I need to achieve this result (don't mind values) :

```
{
"rs0":{
   "c0":"pl",
   "c1":"pl",
   "c2":"pl",
   "c3":"pl",
   "c4":"pl"
},
"rs1":{
   "c0":"pl",
   "c1":"pl",
   "c2":"pl",
   "c3":"pl",
   "c4":"pl"
}
and so on...
```

Please show me what i am doing wrong and how can I complete this?

Comment: You create and encode an array, your desired output shows an encoded object.

Comment: I thing you need this instead: `$d['rs'.$rs]['c'.$c] = $randomRs;`

Comment: It's obvious now :D

Comment: @arkascha hey again, I wonder how to count values in that php array. I want to count for example how many "pl" in that array. I have tried many ways, but none seems to work. Could you help me?

Comment: Short hint: take a look at the `array_walk` function for that. But in general: please ask a new question for new stuff. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @arkascha ;) will do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$d=array();
foreach(range(0, 3) as $rs) {
    foreach(range(0, 5) as $c){

        //here is working php code to generate '$randomRs' by '$rs' and '$c' vars..

        $d['rs'.$rs]['c'.$c] = $randomRs;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am too tired when coding :D You saved my time!

Comment: I wonder how to count values in that php array. I want to count for example how many "pl" in that array. I have tried many ways, but none seems to work. Could you help me?